# NetLogo - sending 8bit parallel port triggers for EEG

Tags: netlogo

I am looking for a way to send 8 bit signals using the parallel port from NetLogo.

I do EEG (Electroencephalogram) research and my goal is to create tasks in NetLogo, and send event codes to the EEG amplifier through the parallel port to mark the events on the EEG data.

Do you have any clue about how I can send 8 bit signals from the parallel port, while running a NetLogo model?

I can probably do this by calling a Matlab script within NetLogo though I am looking for a solution that **doesn't require Matlab**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to go would be to create an extension (in Java or Scala) that creates primitives to send the signals you want. If you can do this in Java, wrapping that in a NetLogo extension is pretty straightforward.

This page covers creating an extension for NetLogo in Java or Scala: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API

Looking around, [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) appears to be the de facto Java library for parallel port communication. This code example is may be helpful: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Parallel_Communications